# insert comma in decimal type

Tags: c#

I Want to insert A comma into adecimal type how i can do it ?

Comment: Is this about formatting a decimal into a string?

Comment: As in `Decimal d = 1003.1234;` -> `1003,1234`, or `1,003.123,4`, or `1 003,123 4`?

Comment: I need like 1,000.33 from regular Decimal

Comment: this code returen 8888.33 but I want 8,888.33 string y =string.Format( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0,0}", p["Regular_price"].ToString());

Comment: @mnaftal Well, I've updated my answer. You need format string equals "{0:0,0.0}"

Comment: We really need to know if this is a sql question or a c# question. Right now it's tagged as both. So which is it?

Comment: @mnaftal Please mark the answer that was most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decimal representation is completely depends on culture. So you need to provide appropriate culture during convertion, like in code below:

```
        double test = 8888.33;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("EN-US"),"{0:0,0.0}",test));
```

Comment: This is - so far - the only answer that works. (For the updated question, and *if* the question is about c#.)

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with a dot.

```
insert  YourTable
        (DecimalColumn)
select  replace('3,14',',','.')
```

Comment: This is not correct. The question is now about thousands separators. Replacing all commas with dots will not help. (That detail wasn't available when this answer was posted...)

Answer (score 2):

This might be your answer - [Formatting Numbers as Strings with Commas in place of Decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559185/formatting-numbers-as-strings-with-commas-in-place-of-decimals)

The top answer there is:

```
  string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.0}", 4.3);
```