# How to validate decimals based on the decimal separator?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to validate numbers and I only know the decimal separator ( dot or comma )

Eg.1: n1=12.4 and n2=1,234.5 -> both are valid for '.' as decimal separator and both invalid 
for ',' as decimal separator.

Eg.2: n1=12,4 and n2=1.234,5 -> both are valid for ',' as decimal separator and both invalid 
for '.' as decimal separator.

What have I tried so far?

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = myDecimalSeparator;
```

and use

```
decimal.Parse(stringValue, cultureInfo);
```

1. Eg1 + '.' => both valid    OK
2. Eg1 + ',' => both throw exception OK
3. Eg2 + ',' => n1 throws exception OK , n2 throws exception WRONG
4. Eg2 + '.' => n1 is 124 WRONG , n2 throws exception OK

What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: This link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559185/formatting-numbers-as-strings-with-commas-in-place-of-decimals

Answer (score 2):

You might try setting the group separator as well - meaning if you know the decimal separator is a comma set the group separator to a period:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = myDecimalSeparator;
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = myGroupSeparator;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `decimal.TryParse` instead to try to catch an exception

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
decimal.Parse(stringValue, cultureInfo.NumberFormat);
```

Only using the culture is insufficient.
Look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t7xswkc6.aspx).

Comment: Culture should work as well - it will pass the NumberFormat through.  See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your normal culture is using the ',' as group separator and '.' as decimal separator. So by creating a new culture from the invariant culture and then setting the decimal separator to '.' is like doing nothing.
On the other hand the newly created culture is still using ',' as a group separator, so by setting the decimal separator to ',' you are telling that ',' is both the group- and the decimal separator.
This is why it works fine test 1 and 2 and it fails in the other tests.