# c# decimal toString() conversion with comma(,)

Tags: c#, type-conversion, tostring

c# `decimal.toString()` conversion problem

**Example:** I have a value in decimal(.1)
when I convert decimal to string using toString() it returns (0,10).  Instead of .(DOT) it returns ,(COMMA).

Comment: Check the current Locale settings - you will need to select one which use . rather than , - The opposite to this question really : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559185/formatting-numbers-as-strings-with-commas-in-place-of-decimals

Comment: Output depends on you `CurrentCulture`, ToString(CultureInfo)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set up dot instead of comma in numeric values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160059/set-up-dot-instead-of-comma-in-numeric-values)

Answer (score 12):

I believe this is to do with the culture/region which your operating system is set to. You can fix/change the way the string is parsed by adding in a format overload in the `.ToString()` method.

For example

```
decimalValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @sivaprakash Feel free to tick my answer as correct then :)

Comment: for marking answer as correct requires 15reputation.i have only 7

Comment: Hey, @sivaprakash just a friednly reminder that you have enough reputation to tick the answer as correct

Answer (score 5):

you have to define the format, it will depend in your local setting or
define the format, using something like this

```
decimal.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"));
```

cheers

Answer (score 4):

For this to be happening, the thread's current culture must be one that uses a separator of comma instead of dot.

You can change this on a per `ToString` basis using the overload for `ToString` that takes a culture:

```
var withDot = myVal.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Alternatively, you can change this for the whole thread by setting the thread's culture before performing any calls to `ToString()`:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

var first = myVal.ToString();
var second = anotherVal.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

For comma (,)

try this:

```
decimalValue.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-tr"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Then your current [culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) is `,` instead of `.`.

If that's not desired you can force the dot with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
decimal num = 0.1m;
string numWithDotAsSeparator = num.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or  `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`

```
string numWithDotAsSeparator = num.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```