# Format number with two zeros after comma?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string-formatting

I have a property on my model like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]
public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
```

When the `TotalPrice` is for example `800,00` then the view shows `$ 800,00` and if the `TotalPrice` is `800,01` (or something like that), the view shows `$ 800,01` and ***this is also correct*** but my client want's that if the `TotalPrice` contains decimals, then the view must show `,00` instead of the decimals. 
I can't format the number with `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]` because it will show `$ 800` and i don't want that.
What's the right formatting for this case?

To make an example:

```
TotalPrice = 800
//Output: $ 800,00
TotalPrice = 800.23
//Output: $ 800,00
TotalPrice = 800.63
//Output: $ 801,00
```

Comment: `format(floor(totalprice))`?

Comment: This should be exactly what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559185/formatting-numbers-as-strings-with-commas-in-place-of-decimals

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for because the user of that post want to show the values after the comma, i want to show only zero's after the comma.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misinterpreted you. Hmm let me look at the code and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Change your attribute get method to return Math.Round(_totalPrice, 0) where _totalPrice is your private attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]
public decimal TotalPrice { 
    get ()
    {return Math.Round(this.TotalPrice);}
    set;
```

}

or if you need to be able to get the decimals from totalprice then

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]
public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]
public readonly decimal TotalRoundedPrice
{
    get ()
    {return Math.Round(this.TotalPrice);}
}
```

Comment: What if i don't have the private attribute?

Comment: I edited to use **this**, but I believe that there is an underlying private attribute to these publicly declared properties.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new string property in your model that outputs the correct value:

```
public string TotalPriceDisplay
{
    get { return Math.Round(this.TotalPrice).ToString ("F"); }
}
```