# How does one convert a number string in US format to a number string in European format?

Tags: c#, wpf, globalization

I am working on a WPF application such that on the UI there is a combo-box that allows the user to select a culture from a drop down list, then on the basis of which culture the user selects I want to convert a numeric string in the existing culture to the one that the user selects from the combo-box. For instance - 2,325,655.65 (US format) vs. 2.325.655,65 (European format).

How to accomplish this in C#?

This is what I have tried so far

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Programs {
    public class ConvertCulture {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.Write("Please enter a number : ");
            var number = Console.ReadLine();
            var doubleValue = double.Parse(number);
            var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
            Console.WriteLine(doubleValue.ToString("N", culture));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate this strings?

Comment: Its populated dynamically by the application but that workflow is all worked out, I just need to work on the conversion, I tried coding it but it doesn't work as expected except for the following culture es-ES

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559185/formatting-numbers-as-strings-with-commas-in-place-of-decimals

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far

Comment: There's a possible design pitfall here in that there is more than one 'European' format, so depending on your application you may need further combinations of settings eg for the UK you will need the US number format, but dd/MM/yyyy date format, and quite likely metric measurement units, for instance.

Comment: @Valentin : I posted what I tried

Answer (score 0):

Use the currency format specifier C. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) the msdn documentation.

For instance:

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")));

// The example displays the following output on a system whose
// current culture is English (United States):
//       $12,345.68
//       $12,345.679
//       kr 12.345,679
```