# c# -ModelState.IsValid returns false only when resource language changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-6

I have one field on my razor view as following

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Duration, new { @class = "form-control txtSite input-large rounded-custom", name = "Duration", @type = "number", min = "0", id = "durationId", required = "true", Tabindex = "1", value = "0" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Duration, "", new { style = "color: red" })
```

I used entity model structure in MVC .The field duration is defined in database table "Activity" (Same model i used on razor) as Float. But the entity metadata shows it as Double as follows.

```
  public Nullable<double> Duration { get; set; }
```

I used partial class as Activity.cs for required validations as follows

```
 [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Activity.Metadata))]
public partial class Activity
{ 
  internal sealed class Metadata
   {
     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Common), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PleaseEnterDuration")]
      public Nullable<double> Duration { get; set; }
   }
}
```

on Controller my code is like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddActivity(Activity model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //Some Code
        }
}
```

The strange is my code works well for float values when my Resource language to display labels is English and its not working when i change it into another language (french).here ModelState.IsValid returning false. And I am getting error as

```
"The value 3.5(any float value) is invalid for Duration."
```

how to fix it for another resource language?. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Refer this Blog http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx

Comment: Don't the French use a comma for a point (3,5) instead of a full-stop (3.5).

Comment: @Dave Becker - yes you right but on database side i taken it as float. Do i change it to string?

Comment: @KulOmkar you probably need to format on the server side (French) so the value `3.5` is output as `3,5` see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559185/formatting-numbers-as-strings-with-commas-in-place-of-decimals

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because your site's culture is set to a language (French) that does not use a dot `.` as a decimal separator. However the entry for `Duration` has a dot in it so your model's state is evaluating to invalid.

In other words your site (server side) is in French culture but the browser or whatever client you are using is NOT in French.

---

**Fix**

You need to synch the language of the client and the server **ON EVERY REQUEST**: Make sure your code to set the culture is executed for each request and not just on application startup. The user can switch languages between requests. Setting `CurrentCulture` to the appropriate language will use that language's numeric formatting, datetime formatting etc.

Additionally, it is suggested but not required to fix your issue, you should also set the `CurrentUICulture`, it will get labels, messages etc. from your resource file for the language (If you have any resource files).

Follow @orhun.begendi answer above to set the above 2 items.

Comment: yes I have resource files as Common.resx and Common.fr.resx which i am using and working fine for Engliah and french version respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override your global.asax.cs file like this

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Create culture info object 
     CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en");

     if(Request.Url.Host.Equals("yourdomain.com",                                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
          ci = new CultureInfo("fr"); //in your case
     }

     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =                                     CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
}
```

Also you can set in begin_request method.

Further information you can check this link
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/778040/beginners-tutorial-on-globalization-and-localizati

Comment: My global.asax.cs is already overwritten with code like u mentioned. And all other texts , Date etc. are  are working on my system in local language

Comment: On french, there is some pointing problem, can you check thread culture after request ? You must specify there, if you get other culture, there is the problem. Also you can check with change web browser's culture info as well. Sometimes like on chrome; computer culture info applied on web page, for proper test you must be change that also.

Comment: @OmkarKulkarni make sure your code to set the culture is executed for each request and not just on application startup. The user can switch languages between requests.

Comment: @Coding Yoshi - Got it , my code to set culture was executed only on application start up and accordingly the labels were coming in that culture.